# How to use sed to replace keys in a file using a regex?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I would like to modify a file to replace keys, suppose these keys are in the file as:

```
42NM
52NM
23NO
XNNM
```

I would like to replace anything with NM, with the word "Okay".

```
 1 #!bin/bash/
 2 
 3 if [ -f KeyFile]
 4 then
 5         sed 's/[0-9][0-9]NM/Okay/g' KeyFile
 6 else
 7         echo "File does not exist or cannot be found."
 8 fi
 9 
10 exit 0
```

I ran the command:

```
chmod a+x FindKeys
```

and then, when I attempt to run the script, I get:

```
-bash-3.00$ ./FindKeys
-bash: ./FindKeys: bin/bash/: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I seem to have two problems, one the script file is not running correctly, and two the `sed` command is not working.

Comment: `sed -i 's/NM/Okay/' KeyFile`

Comment: your first line is missing a `/` , it should be: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: If you write the command `which bash` in the CLI, what gets printed?

Comment: When I do `which bash`, I get `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Line 1**: Your hashbang line is not correct, use:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

**Line 3**: Take care with the `test` utility (it needs a space before the closing `]`):

```
if [ -f KeyFile ]
```

**Line 5**: In the `sed` command, use `-i` to activate in-place editing of `sed`, else the edits are only printed to the stdout:

```
sed -i 's/[0-9][0-9]NM/Okay/g' KeyFile
```

Comment: I have made those changes though I still get:`-bash: ./FindKeys: /bin/bash/: bad interpreter: Not a directory`

Comment: @JuanDavila sry, a typo, see my edit: `#!/bin/bash`, without the ending slash

Comment: Additional advice (which wasn't requested but I'm giving anyway): on line 7, I suggest redirecting the `echo` to stderr (i.e. append `>&2`), and exit with a non-zero status.  This is really useful for composition (calling this script from another, or from a Makefile, etc.).

Comment: I was able to get this to work, running the command directly in the shell prompt, though for whatever reason I still get the "bad interpreter error" when using it in a script.